# What does the "C" mean in "Mater. Sci. Eng. C"

Tags: science, materials-science

ISO4 standard naming for the "Materials Science" field is as follows:

- Mater. Sci. Eng. C
- Material Science & Engineering: C

What does the **C** mean?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The ISO code does not refer to the field, but to a [journal](https://www.journals.elsevier.com/materials-science-and-engineering-c). The C is not an abbreviation; rather there are 4 journals with this name, each with a different focus, indexed A, B, C, and R.

- A focuses on Structural Materials: Properties, Microstructure and Processing
- B focuses on Advanced Functional Solid-State Materials
- C focuses on Materials for Biological Applications
- R is for review articles

Such a nomenclature is generally used when a journal's scope has become too broad and it needs to be split into multiple journals. Physical Review uses a similar system, for example.

Comment: Are these to be interpreted as "1, 2, 3" e.g.: books in a series, like University classes numbered 101, 102, 103, etc? Or do they stand alone, or have entirely different purposes (not belong in a series.)

Comment: @DamonBlais Like different brothers or sisters from a single family. Or like parallel similar  subjects at a single uni, each oriented to slightly different audience. They do not follow each other in series, thy are independent branches focused elsewhere.

Comment: @DamonBlais - Once upon a time there was just Physical Review, which covered all aspects of physics. Then they got more and more good articles submitted. So they split the journal, each part focusing. Phys Rev A is atomic, molecular, optical, and quantum. Phys Rev B is condensed matter and materials, Phys Rev C is nuclear physics, etc. All under the Physical Review umbrella, but you pick the field(s) you are interested in.